# How to Install USARSim package

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently installed USARSIm on windows7 and ROS groovy on ubuntu 11.10. **Question 1**:How to add the package usarsim or usarsim_inf? When I type roscd usarsim_inf (in ubuntu terminal); then error comes as no such package/satck 'usarsim_inf'.

**Question 2**: where to include usarsim.launch file?

**Question 3**: I have gone through  http://sourceforge.net/p/usarsimros/code/ci/master/tree/; but how to use this to build a package? Also gone through https://github.com/makokal/usarsim-ros but it unable to connect to github.com.

**Question 4**: Can we provide our own predefined map without using slam in ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/78426/how-to-install-usarsim-package/) by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2013-09-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. I suggest you modify your ~/.bashrc file by adding the following line:
   export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/path/to/usarsim-code:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
2. What do you mean exactly? In /path/to/usarsim-code/usarsim_inf/launch you find the usarsim.launch template file together with some working examples
3. I did not know the repo by Billy Okal, I'll try it. However I downloaded the software from sourceforge and managed to compile only the usarsim_inf package. Simply cd to the usarsim_inf directory and enter make
4. yes, look for the map_server entry in the wiki

---

Originally posted by [kr1zz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4727/kr1zz/) with karma: 116 on 2013-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kr1zz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4727/kr1zz/) on 2013-09-30**:
The wiki page is http://wiki.ros.org/map_server

**Comment by [kr1zz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4727/kr1zz/) on 2013-09-30**:
By the way, did you manage to make USARSimRos work, in the end? I think there's a bug in USARSimRos, I posted a comment about it, with a workaround here: http://sourceforge.net/p/usarsimros/discussion/general/thread/baca98c8/

**Comment by [kr1zz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4727/kr1zz/) on 2013-09-30**:
forgive the comments but I was unable to put urls into the text of the answer :P

**Comment by [sumant](https://answers.ros.org/users/20291/sumant/) on 2014-09-26**:
hello @kr1zz,
i am having same problem. do you found any solution. please help if any.